# Не работает transition на изменении background

Tags: css, css3, css-animation, transition

Подскажите, почему не отрабатывает transition на изменение background, при наведении курсора? 
[Пример кода](http://codepen.io/Econavi/pen/EWEmKK)

```
.button {
    display:  inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 42px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    background: linear-gradient(orange, red);
    position: absolute;
    transition: 2s background;
}
.button:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(yellow, red);
}

.button:active {
    background: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
}

.button::selection {
    background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: transition и  gradient не дружат, только через хак.

Answer (score 3):

Хак с использованием :after :

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 42px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  background: linear-gradient(orange, red);
  position: absolute;
  z-index:1
}
.button:after{
  border-radius: 10px;
  z-index:2;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: opacity 2s;
  opacity:0;
  background:linear-gradient(red, yellow);
}
.button:hover:after{opacity:1}
```

```html
<div class="button" ></div>
```